# what is the best practice for implementing a class which contains several update methods with intention of less duplicate code?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Lets say im having following methods

```
public class Class1
{
        public void UpdateMethod1()
        {
            Entities.StaticDataEntities entities=new StaticDataEntities();
            //insert some items or make some changes in entity
            entities.SaveChanges();
        }
        public void UpdateMethod2()
        {
            Entities.StaticDataEntities entities=new StaticDataEntities();
            //insert some items or make some changes in entity
            entities.SaveChanges();
        }
        ....
}
```

what is the best approach to implement such a example which contains several methods with update responsibility? my intention is to remove the extra `entities.SaveChanges();` and `Entities.StaticDataEntities entities=new StaticDataEntities();` from my code and bring it to a wrapper class or something like that. by the way if the question title is not appropriate help to change it.

Comment: How are these update methods related?

Comment: lets say in updatemethod1, I change the cities table and in updatemethod2 I change the countries table and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try approach like this:

```
public class Class1
{
    public void UpdateMethod1()
    {
        UpdateWrapper(entities => {
            //insert some items or make some changes in entity
        }); 
    }
    public void UpdateMethod2()
    {
        UpdateWrapper(entities => {
            //insert some items or make some changes in entity
        });                       
    }

    private static void UpdateWrapper(Action<StaticDataEntities> update)
    {
        var entities = new StaticDataEntities();
        update(entities);
        entities.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**Update**

> this is good, but still I need to use updatewrapper method in every single method, is there any other way like bring the savechanges method in another class and layer and call that layer ?

The simplest way is to carry `UpdateWrapper` out of the class to a helper and refactor it to be like this:

```
public static class UpdateHelper
{
    // where ObjectContext is the base class for 'StaticDataEntities' that contains ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
    public static int Update<T>(Action<T> action) where T : ObjectContext, new()
    {
        var entities = new T();
        action(entities);
        return entities.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Also `Class1` should also be refactored to this:

```
public class Class1
{
    public void UpdateMethod1(StaticDataEntities entities)
    {            
        //insert some items or make some changes in entity
    }
    public void UpdateMethod2(StaticDataEntities entities)
    {            
        //insert some items or make some changes in entity
    }        
}
```

Then you can use it in this way:

```
var x = new Class1();
UpdateHelper.Update<StaticDataEntities>(x.UpdateMethod1); // via a method group
UpdateHelper.Update<StaticDataEntities>(o => x.UpdateMethod2(o)); // via classic lambda
```

Comment: this is good, but still I need to use updatewrapper method in every single method, is there any other way like bring the savechanges method in another class and layer and call that layer ?